# display a scrollable container beneath other containers in a JFrame

Tags: jframe

I want to display the following inside a JFrame:

At the top a grid containing labels and having just the necessary height.
Just beneath that a single button.
the rest of the space below that button should be filled by a vertical scrollable container where i can add stuff later. So far i tried:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
frame.add(panel);

JButton button = new JButton("search");
frame.add(button);

JPanel results = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(results);
frame.add(scroll);
```

But it does not give the scroll pane any space and instead puts all the space around the grid.
how can make the scroll pane expand to fill the remaining height?
Or should i use other components/layouts to achieve what i want?